# How do I fix this error ? "the operator is undefined for the argument type(s) entry, entry"

Tags: java

I have just created an insertion method to sort the array, this is the code that I have done in that method;

```
public static void insertionSort (Entry[] array2){
    for (int i =0; i < array2.length; i++){
        Entry values = array2[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while (j >=0 && array2[j] > values){
            array2[j+1] = array2[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        array2[j+1] = values;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a red line under the "array2[j] > values"

Comment: How is it supposed to interpret `Entry > Entry`?

Comment: Sorry i missed out, I have got a class called Entry which implements from the Comparable interface and it has a generic ("<entry>").

Comment: Then you should use `array2[j].compareTo(values)`

Comment: Can you post the code for your Entry class as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while (j >=0 && array2[j] > values){
```

You are comparing two values of type Entry with '>', they can't be compared like that.

If you are using Map.Entry, it doesn't implement Comparable, so even compareTo would fail. Think about what you want to compare, keys or values?

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this, Is there anything that I could look up to get more about this?

Comment: @user3443890 Sure. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) could be of some help. What are you exactly trying to compare?

Comment: I am trying to sort these added entries in my directory using the insertion method that I have just created

Comment: @user3443890 If the entries come from a map, you probably want to sort them by key. The comparasion method depends on the type of the key, but you probably want something like array2[j].getKey().compareTo(values.getKey()) > 0

Comment: The entries are coming from an Array

Comment: @user3443890 I can't tell you for sure without seeing the Entry class, but you should be able to use array2[j].compareTo(values) > 0 as a replacement for array2[j] > values.

Comment: @user3443890 Glad to be of help :) You should mark the question as solved now. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

If your `Entry` class implements `Comparable`, then you should replace

```
array2[j] > values
```

with

```
array2[j].compareTo(values) > 0
```

...because Java doesn't allow operator overloading, so you have to just call the `compareTo` method.

Comment: sorry, so in my compareTo method in the entry class which implements from Comparable, what should I have in that method

Comment: It depends what's in your entry class, which you haven't shown us.